# Simple query to include all columns based upon the MAX of one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read through a lot of other articles and at this point I think I'm just beating my head against a wall. How would I replace this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeInformation
```

I want to see all columns in table `EmployeeInformation` with ONLY the most recent `RateChangeDate`. I've tried `MAX(RateChangeDate)`. An acceptable output would replace the current `Walters, Rob` rows by:

```
Walters, Rob    Senior Tool Designer    29.8462 2011-12-15 00:00:00.000 rob0@adventure-works.com
```

[MSSQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdz07.png)

Comment: I'm not going to give you code that works -- you can't put in a picture like this if you want me to give you the code -- paste the actual code.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please include text as text, not a link/image. Format code & tables using code blocks. PS What does "tried MAX" mean? Show us.

Comment: Observe how this non-self-contained question has evoked a bunch of poor quality (1st version) answers trying for imaginary unicorn points instead of helping you clearly ask for and get what you want. This (and being searchable & copy & pasteable) is why needed content should be inline. And why questions should be expressed & formatted clearly, including code & tables/rows & output. And why unclear questions are to be downvoted & questions re code with no [mcve] are to be closed (ie have answers locked out until improved). And why unclear questions should not be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from EmployeeInformation
Where RateChangeDate =
    (Select Max(RateChangeDate) 
     from EmployeeInformation)
```

latest per employee:

```
Select * from EmployeeInformation e
Where RateChangeDate =
    (Select Max(RateChangeDate) 
     from EmployeeInformation
     where emplyeeId = e.emplyeeId )
```

Comment: This does not work -- only give one value per employee.

Comment: You didn't say the latest `RateChangeDate` *per each employee*.

Comment: I didn't say anything -- that is clearly what the OP wanted not just one line of result.

Comment: His desired output IS only one row.

Comment: look at the picture -- he wants to replace the 3 rows for that one person with one row.  -- one row for that walter guy.

Comment: sorry, I don't look at pictures in links in questions.

Comment: I don't blame you.  But in this case it matters

Comment: @CharlesBretana Right, you don't look at links. The question should not have links. Therefore the question is unclear. So you should downvote & close vote & comment, not answer.

Comment: @philipxy, Granted, you are probably right, for all the obvious reasons. (please don't bother to elaborate!) I just tend to try to help if I can. Habit.

Answer (score 0):

```
With EmpInfo AS
(
  SELECT lastname + ', ' + firstname as fullname, jobtitle, rate, ratechangedate, emailaddress,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lastname + ', ' + firstname BY ORDER BY RateChangeDate DESC) as RN 
   --- etc all joins
)
SELECT *
FROM EmpInfo
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Order by RateChangeDate

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT *
  FROM EmployeeInformation
 WHERE RateChangeDate = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(RateChangeDate)
                           FROM EmployeeInformation)
```

Comment: This does not work -- only give one value per employee.

Comment: His question was not clear. It is assumed that he wants only the latest.

Comment: The link, although it should be inline as text, makes the question clearer. If it is not clear, downvote & close vote & comment, don't answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number as below:

```
Select top(1) with ties * from EmployeeInformation
   Order by Row_Number() over(partition by [Name] order by RateChangeDate Desc)
```

Comment: does row_number() work in an order by statement?  Not in all versions for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subqueries.

Something like this

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tablename 
 WHERE fullname IN (SELECT fullname 
                    FROM tablename 
                    WHERE Ratechangedate IN (SELECT MAX(Ratechangedate) 
                                             FROM tablename))
```

Inner most select selects your max date column, then it selects the fullname column for this max date and then it selects all rows with this fullname.

Comment: The user does not want just one row -- he wants to get one row PER employee

Comment: This will still only get one row

Comment: Please format your code correcty. Look at the formatted version before you post. See editing help.